# Nested SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables like this:

```
product_table[ product_id, product_name,original_store_id, destination_store id]
```

and

```
store_table[ store_id, establishment_date, location]
```

What I want to find is: From all those products that are shipped TO stores with no establishment date, how many of them are shipped FROM stores with establishment date?

This is my query:

```
SELECT count(a.product_id) as count_of_products
FROM product_table a
JOIN store_table b
ON a.original_store_id = b.store_id AND a.destination_store_id = b.store_id
WHERE b.establishment_date IS NULL
```

I understand this should be a nested query, but how do I put them here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding a second join to the `store_table` table to further restrict to only products shipped from stores with an establishment date:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.product_id) AS count_of_products
FROM product_table a
INNER JOIN store_table b
    ON a.destination_store_id = b.store_id
INNER JOIN store_table c
    ON a.original_store_id = c.store_id
WHERE
    b.establishment_date IS NULL AND
    c.establishment_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: . . Use meaningful table aliases, not meaningless letters.